# Pact provider doesn't send verification to Pact Broker

Tags: gradle, pact, pact-jvm, pact-java

I am new in Pact (consumer-driven testing) and gradle, I used this famous workshop to try Pact with Java and Pact Brocker https://github.com/Mikuu/Pact-JVM-Example, but never works the final part when provider sends the verification to the Pact Broker. It works manually via REST API, but using the project never sends the verifications. Please help to understand what happens (probably something is missing, some library or annotation?)

I attach the debug log when producer tries to send the verification to the Pact Broker (local Broker in docker using gradle with `./gradlew :example-provider:pactVerify`). I guess that the body of POST request is missing.

```
14:22:59.469 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {}->http://localhost:80
14:22:59.469 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:80
14:22:59.470 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established 127.0.0.1:55770<->127.0.0.1:80
14:22:59.470 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request POST /pacts/provider/ExampleProvider/consumer/JunitRuleMultipleInteractionsConsumer/pact-version/e66d465478e1934bca0ad9b905a2f83835af481d/verification-results HTTP/1.1
14:22:59.470 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:22:59.470 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:22:59.492 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-255: Close connection
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 255][route: {}->http://localhost:80][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute verifyPact for :example-provider:pactVerify_ExampleProvider'
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':example-provider:pactVerify_ExampleProvider'
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :example-provider:pactVerify_ExampleProvider'
14:22:59.493 [null] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] 
14:22:59.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :example-provider:pactVerify_ExampleProvider' completed
14:22:59.493 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :example-provider:pactVerify_ExampleProvider (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.96 secs.
```

Comment: You'll need to look at your pact broker logs, because if the POST is logged there the verification results are being published. You can enable debugging with the Apache HTTP client to see the actual request and response.

Answer (score 0):

The pact example seems to be missing one important step: **Adding the @PactBroker annotation**

Below the @Pact annotation, there should be an annotation

```
@PactBroker(port = PORT_NUM , host = HOST_NAME)
```

You can find an example here [at the official repo](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-provider-junit)